# APEX on Oracle XE using https

Tags: oracle, https, oracle-apex, oracle-xe

Is it possible to configure the http server that comes with Oracle XE so that it can use https?

I need to deploy an APEX app for a charity (it wasn't me who selected apex) so the deployment needs to be as cheap as possible.

All help gratefully received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The http server that comes with Oracle XE is an internal web server which only understands HTTP. The recommended practice for SSL or adding support for other functionality is to set up an Apache server as proxy. This message from the oracle forums will describe the process.

http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=1142169